# Громкость звука в Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Условно проигрываю файл Music.mp3. Нашел функцию `volume(0-1)`, где `0` - глушит, где `1` - включает, что делает ее непригодной. Мне нужно изменять громкость музыки, например: 10%-100%. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить

Comment: А `0.5` не сработает?

Comment: Благодарю, не думал :)

Comment: Зря, думать - приятно. :)